# PostgreSQL perent with child list

Tags: postgresql

I have a table structured as

```
Id int(10)
ROOT_ID int(10) --reference I'd
Name
```

This table contain structure of parants and sons. Example data

```
Id | parent | name
 1     Null     A
 2     1        B
 3     1        C
 4     Null     D
 5     4        E
 6     5        F
```

The example contain a simple heritage example 
I would like to find using PostgreSQL all parent origin with child list

something like

```
Id | name | all Childs
1     A        B,C
4     D        E,F
```

Can I do this through PostgreSQL?
Or i should work it through java  recursion after pulling the rows

Comment: Does `all Childs` represent all _descendants_ at any depth?  If not, then why is `F` listed as a child of `D`?

Comment: Yes, i need all descendants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find all descendant records you need to use recursive query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(root_parent, id, parent, name) AS (
    SELECT id as root_parent, id, parent, name FROM your_table WHERE parent IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.root_parent, your_table.id, your_table.parent, your_table.name FROM your_table, t WHERE your_table.parent = t.id
)
SELECT t.root_parent as id, your_table.name, array_agg(t.name) as children
FROM t
JOIN your_table ON your_table.id = t.root_parent
WHERE t.parent IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t.root_parent, your_table.name
ORDER BY t.root_parent
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/AEA93879

You can read about recursive queries in [PostgreSQL documentaion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)

---

The above query might seem too confusing at first, let me explain it a little. It consists of 2 parts: a recursive query itself, and a select-query. Here's the output of the recursive query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(root_parent, id, parent, name) AS (
    SELECT id as root_parent, id, parent, name FROM your_table WHERE parent IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.root_parent, your_table.id, your_table.parent, your_table.name FROM your_table, t WHERE your_table.parent = t.id
)
SELECT * FROM t

-----------------------------------
| root_parent | id | parent | name |
|1            |1   |        |"A"   |
|4            |4   |        |"D"   |
|1            |2   |1       |"B"   |
|1            |3   |1       |"C"   |
|4            |5   |4       |"E"   |
|4            |6   |5       |"F"   |
------------------------------------
```

And the second part of the query just performs a grouping so that a list of children is shown for every root record.